# What is the purpose of the StringSegment class?

Tags: c#

In the **Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives** package lib there is a class `StringSegment` for which the comments indicate that it is:

> An optimized representation of a substring.

I was unaware of this particular class, until I discovered [aspnet announcement #244](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/244), stating: *Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers converted to use StringSegments*.

Still, looking at the [implementation of the StringSegment](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives/StringSegment.cs) class, I fail to see what purpose it actually serves. I see a buffer, which I guess would indicate better manipulation on partial characters (the 'segment' part perhaps?). I also see several helper functions which are closely related - if not identical - in behaviour to those already available at regular strings, such as StartsWith/Endswith, Substring etc. The [aspnet-core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.stringsegment) list these in full, but again this also lacks context on "why" it should be used.

So what exactly is the purpose of the `StringSegment` class and in which scenarios is it applicable to use it?

Is it useful to call the class in my application code, when I manipulate strings?
Can we have an example, where it will be beneficial?

Comment: Well, http headers are a good example.  They have to be parsed, but client code is rarely interested in them.  So generating them lazily avoids a bunch of GC garbage.

Comment: @HansPassant You don't need `StringSegment` for that.  In that case you can just have the headers parsed when the `Headers` property of the request is fetched.  If you create `StringSegments` then you're creating all of the objects for all of the string segments unnecessarily.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It lets you perform a variety of string operations on a substring of another string, *without* actually calling `Substring()` and creating a new string object. It's roughly analogous to the way in C you can have a pointer into the middle of a string.

Comment: As mentioned to your earlier comment, no, that's just not true.  The point isn't to defer the operator until later.  The *goal* is to *avoid doing the operation at all*.  If you find yourself using `Value` of a StringSegment often, you're not getting any benefit of it, and you're likely causing yourself *problems*.  Of course, that doesn't mean you should *never* use this, but rather, that you should only be calling this on a small portion of the instances you create.

Comment: @Servy Yes, clearly, if somebody gets `Value` twice, the whole thing becomes counterproductive -- unless there's some optimization there where the second call to `Buffer.Substring(Offset, Length);` will return the same interned string object.

Comment: No, if they call value on every substring *once* they're still not benefiting from using it.  The whole purpose of the class is that you should be calling it *less than once per instance*, ideally *significantly* less, else you should just be using regular substrings.

Comment: @Servy I guess I should have said that in so many words. "If nobody ever calls `Value.get`, `Substring` never actually gets called" seemed sufficient to me at the time. Updating.

Comment: @Servy If "deferred" is taken to imply that it *will* be called, that's not the word I want -- but I'm drawing a total blank on what would be a better term.

Comment: Again, you seem to not understand the purpose of the type.  If you just want to defer a call to `Substring` you just need a `Func<string>` that calls `Substring`; there's no reason for a new type to accomplish that.  The whole point is to *perform operations on it*, and actually consume it as a meaningful value *without ever actually resolving it to a string*.  If you're not doing that, you have no reason to use the type.

Comment: @Servy What sort of operations?

Comment: Look at all of it's methods.  Any of those (except `ToString`).  (And also any of the properties *besides* `Value`.)

Comment: Ah, good point. Thanks.

Comment: @Servy Couldn't we just use `ReadOnlySpan<char>` for this purpose?

Comment: @silkfire This is more or less the managed version of that, with a few other methods based on the more specific knowledge that it's a span of string, rather than arbitrary bytes.  That it has a method to convert it to that indicates that it's more or less the same concept and implementation, but a a slightly higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

When parsing text many new string objects may be created or copied. This class in theory would help reduce memory used when handling large substrings. Other languages have similar concepts (see std::string_view in C++17)